# t-sql LEFT OUTER JOIN Conundrum

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Some simple data sets to illustrate the issue:

```
SELECT * FROM LeftTable

OID Name    LeftBlah
1   Name1   LeftBlah1
2   Name2   LeftBlah2

SELECT * FROM JoinTable

OID Name    RightBlah
1   Name1   RightBlah1
2   Name1-Dumb1 RightBlah1-Dumb1
3   Name1-Dumb2 RightBlah1-Dumb2
4   Name2-Dumb1 RightBlah2-Dumb1
5   Name2-Dumb2 RightBlah2-Dumb2
```

One of the ways I query these tables, followed by the query output:

```
SELECT L.Name, L.LeftBlah, J.Name AS JName, J.RightBlah, LEFT(J.Name, 5) AS WFT
FROM LeftTable AS L
LEFT OUTER JOIN JoinTable AS J ON (L.Name = J.Name)

Name    LeftBlah    JName   RightBlah   WFT
Name1   LeftBlah1   Name1   RightBlah1  Name1
Name2   LeftBlah2   NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Another way I query these tables, followed by the query output:

```
SELECT L.Name, L.LeftBlah, J.Name AS JName, J.RightBlah, LEFT(J.Name, 5) AS WFT
FROM LeftTable AS L
LEFT OUTER JOIN JoinTable AS J ON (L.Name = LEFT(J.Name, 5))

Name    LeftBlah    JName   RightBlah   WFT
Name1   LeftBlah1   Name1   RightBlah1  Name1
Name1   LeftBlah1   Name1-Dumb1 RightBlah1-Dumb1    Name1
Name1   LeftBlah1   Name1-Dumb2 RightBlah1-Dumb2    Name1
Name2   LeftBlah2   Name2-Dumb1 RightBlah2-Dumb1    Name2
Name2   LeftBlah2   Name2-Dumb2 RightBlah2-Dumb2    Name2
```

The table design is dumb, but I can't change it.  The entries with '-' in the second table's name field are some joker's 'magic stringy' way of showing they are sub-details of the 'main things' (same name in both tables).  If a 'main thing' is missing from the second table, this could represent *either* a data problem *or* a normal condition (heh, heh)... Missing can be normal if there are no sub-details, but it is possible for a main thing to be there without sub-details, too.  The first query shows 'main things' as you would expect - just null data from the second table.  The second query leaves out the null-null-null row.

At first, I thought this was a problem with LEFT OUTER JOIN, however, it has done its job of bringing back every row in the first table.  If it brought back a null-null-null row for Name2, it would probably bring one back for Name1 and I sure wouldn't want that.

Interestingly, I can actually get what I want with a UNION of the two queries. I don't understand why I don't get back a bunch of duplicate rows, but I'm a reluctant coder who is *far* more interested in getting the result I want than I am in understanding all of the coding intricacies.  Unfortunately, the result I want is going to need to run faster than a simple UNION of the two query forms against the real data I'm working with.

So, finally, my question:  Is there a way to get the UNION'd result in some clever way that avoids the wastefulness of that approach that makes for slow execution?

Comment: *The table design is dumb...* Indeed it is. I like your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

[UNION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) by default does a distinct.  If you want duplicate then use UNION ALL.

UNION is pretty efficient and may be the best approach here.  Work on optimizing the individual selects.

I think you can change the second to a join (not left) and add and (L.Name <> J.Name)